# How to increment count for Semantic-UI Table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5

This might be a nooby question,but I have not found anything online to how to do this.

I have a table that shows a leader-board for highest points.
This is how it looks:
[image: Table for leader-boards]

I need to get a count for each row that there is a username, so if there is 23 records in that table, then I need 1-23 displayed on the left where the # is at.

I tried using this:

```html
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
     {{ $i }}
@endfor
```

in my table:

```html
            <table class="ui celled striped selectable inverted table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" class="center aligned">
                            Leaderboards
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th class="center aligned">Username</th>
                        <th class="center aligned"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> Points</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach ($points as $point)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           #
                        </td>
                        <td class="center aligned"> {{ $point->username }}</td>
                        <td class="center aligned"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> {{ $point->points }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

But I keep on getting a loop from 1-10 in ONE row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a counter variable `$i` and increment it at the end of your loop, like this:

```
<table class="ui celled striped selectable inverted table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" class="center aligned">
                            Leaderboards
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th class="center aligned">Username</th>
                        <th class="center aligned"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> Points</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php $i = 0; ?>
                @foreach ($points as $point)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                           # {{ $i }}
                        </td>
                        <td class="center aligned"> {{ $point->username }}</td>
                        <td class="center aligned"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> {{ $point->points }}</td>
                    </tr>
                <?php $i++; ?>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
```